# How to choose the initial clusters for K-mean from Tf-IDF vectors

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means, text-mining, tf-idf

I'm working with text clustering. I want to select specific documents (as a vector) to be a centroID fo k-means.

I have created the TF-IDF for my dataset by using Mahout, and I would like to choose the initial clusters from TFIDF vectors.

Anyone has an idea how I can specify the initial centroids in Mahout?

Comment: Mahout has built-in selection of centroids, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, Mahout can select the centroid randomlly or by using Canopy, but I would like to select them manually.

Comment: It also has an option to specify them manually.

Answer (score 0):

bin/mahout kmeans
    -c **input clusters directory**
    -k **optional number of initial clusters to sample from input vectors**

If the -k argument is supplied, any clusters in the -c directory will be overwritten and -k random points will be sampled from the input vectors to become the initial cluster centers.

Reference: https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be using [Cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) instead of TF-IDF, by looking at documents that are the farthest away from one another. Something like this:

1. Pick a document 1.
2. Pick the farthest document 2 from document 1.
3. Pick the farthest document from documents 1 and 2.
4. etc

Taking a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) might help as well.